# How to check how many times some values are duplicated?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have table like below:

```
city      | segment
------------------
London    | A
London    | B
New York  | A
Berlin    | B
Barcelona | C
Barcelona | H
Barcelona | E
```

Each city should have only one segment, but as you can see there are two cities (London and Barcelona) that have more than one segment.

It is essential that in result table I need only these cities which have > 1 segmnet

As a result I need somethig like below:

- city - city based on table above
- no_segments - number of segments which have defined city based on table above
- segments - segments of defined city based on table above

  | city | no_segments | segments |
  | --- | --- | --- |
  | London | 2 | A |
  |  |  | B |
  | Barcelona | 3 | C |
  |  |  | H |
  |  |  | E |

How can I do that in Oracle?

Comment: Should your report really only show City and No_Segments once, on the first row for each such city? How are you going to deal with page breaks? (where a city list begins at the bottom of one page but must continue on the next page) - do you need to repeat the headings (city and no_segments) at the top of the new page? Etc. All such can be addressed much more easily in the reporting software - even SQL Developer - than in the SQL query itself. If you look at it this way, do you have **two** questions, not one? One about the query, and the other about formatting the output?

Answer (score 0):

```
;with cte as (
Select city, count(seg) as cntseg
From table1
Group by city having count(seg) > 1
)
Select a.city, b.cntseg, a.seg
From table1 as a join cte as b
On a.city = b.city
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `COUNT(*) OVER ()`(*in order to get number of segments*) and `ROW_NUMBER()`(*in order to prepare the results those will be conditionally displayed*) analytic functions such as

```sql
WITH t1 AS
(
 SELECT city, 
        segment,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY city) AS no_segments,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY city ORDER BY segment) rn
   FROM t
)
SELECT DECODE(rn,1,city) AS city, 
       DECODE(rn,1,no_segments) AS no_segments, 
       segment
  FROM t1
 WHERE no_segments > 1      
 ORDER BY t1.city, segment
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=57bb7a128d6c1989bddeb5df22e681da)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is:

```sql
SELECT NULLIF(CITY, PREV_CITY) AS CITY,
       SEGMENT
  FROM (SELECT CITY,
               LAG(CITY) OVER (ORDER BY CITY DESC) AS PREV_CITY,
               SEGMENT,
               COUNT(SEGMENT) OVER (PARTITION BY CITY) AS CITY_SEGMENT_COUNT
        FROM CITY_SEGMENTS)
  WHERE CITY_SEGMENT_COUNT > 1
```

Using `LAG()` to determine the "previous" CITY allows us to directly compare the `CITY` values, which in my mind is clearer that using ROW_NUMBER = 1.

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=704b5e167f9e13aed8627b4badc7fe5b)